# Using sudo apt-get install, why no source code?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, source-code

I was trying to install a package for robotic operational system (ROS). And I just go ahead and type `sudo apt-get install <package>`

After installation, I see a list of files in `/opt/share` folders, which are the packages I want.

But if I go  into `src`, the source code (.cpp files) aren't there.

I can see the source code if I go to developer's github pages, but how come the package is installed without using the source code? How can I download the source code and install the package using `apt-get install` command?

Comment: As a sidenote, I think it is quite unusual for something to land in `/opt/share` from standard repositories, isn't it?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes. There is NO default software that uses /opt/ Would be a violation of the filesystem hierarchy system.

Answer (score 10):

By default `apt-get install` does not download the source codes of packages. There is a specific `apt-get` option to do that which is `source`.

From `man apt-get`:

> source
>              source causes apt-get to fetch source packages. APT will examine the available packages to decide which source package
>              to fetch. It will then find and download into the current directory the newest available version of that source package
>              while respecting the default release, set with the option APT::Default-Release, the -t option or per package with the
>              pkg/release syntax, if possible.
>
> Source packages are tracked separately from binary packages via deb-src lines in the sources.list(5) file. This means
>              that you will need to add such a line for each repository you want to get sources from; otherwise you will probably get
>              either the wrong (too old/too new) source versions or none at all.

So the syntax to download the source package of something to the current directory would be (no need to be `root`):

```
apt-get source <package_name>
```

Also note that as the `man` pages says you need to have the `deb-src` repositories enabled for all the regular `deb` repositories you want to keep track of source packages. The simplest way to do that would be to just add `-src` to the original repo's initial `deb` string:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
```

On a different note, you might have checked the `/usr/src` directory which is the designated place for all kernel sources.

Answer (score 2):

@heemayl answer tells you how to get the source code but in case you are wondering

> how come the package is installed without using the source code?

It is because Ubunutu does not build packages from source and instead downloads precompiled binaries.

A distro like Gentoo Linux however would download the source and build a package locally.